# How to transform a python function of multiple parameters to one that accepts a list?

Tags: python

I have a python function of many parameters

```
foo(x_1,...x_N)
```

Is there a pythonic way to transform it to a function that accepts a list of numpy.array?

Comment: Do you mean I could have used foo directly for numpy.array?

Comment: make your function accept only one argument and then put all your params into a `np.array`

Comment: Or you need `foo(*X)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
foo(*x)  # calls foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. But what is the strange syntax? Does '*' mean dereference?

Comment: That syntax means pass each element of the iterable as a positional argument. There's also `**dict` for keyword args.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define the function as `def foo(mylist)` and then do whatever you want with it inside the function.

```
def foo(mylist):
    ''' mylist: an iterable '''
    for item in mylist: # example
        print(item)
```

Comment: @zell Why would it not be?